# Hiding rain drain pipe below the sidewalk

Tags: drain, sidewalk

I have a 100mm pipe (4") that comes under the garage ramp and outputs the rain water to the street. My problem is that I couldn't have the pipe goes straight to the street because of the slope needed, so I diverted the pipe 45° at the sidewalk point.

The pipe end sits a bit above the curb level, so now I need to find a way to hide this pipe. I thought of maybe using a drain grate, but I couldn't find anyone with 45° corners (I could weld something, but I would be a very tedious work). Another idea is using a heat blower to compress the pipe to that it goes below the curb level, but I think this might create clogging problems.

Any other choices?

EDIT: Added a picture of the pipe in question

[image: diagram]

[image: actual picture]

Comment: An actual picture of the end you "want to hide" would be much more useful than the diagram...

Comment: Done. Don't know why, my first thought was to make a diagram instead of picture.

Comment: You're saying somebody is going to come along later and pour a sidewalk on top of that pipe?

Comment: Yes, this is why I need to make something (maybe a grate) so that it sits a few centimeters below the sidewalk level.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you move the end a little further uphill and empty the pipe into some kind of culvert drain or splash block that slopes down to the curb?

[image]

Or you could use a pipe fixture like this:

[image]

There's a brand name behind that thing ([Mitered Drain](http://www.mitereddrain.com/)), and I'm not sure there are identical alternatives, so I'll go ahead and identify the brand. I'm not their spokesman. They just have the solution that's identical to what came into my head when I saw your question.

Or maybe you could transition to a rectangular section of pipe:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Those drains don't exist in Brazil, and the circular to rectangular tube has the problem of cloging.

Comment: What are you planning on running down that drain?  ;-) You might also be able to do something like pour a concrete box around it, put a grate in the front and bury it in some landscaping?

Answer (score 0):

Make a grate, regular one. But, before that, shorten Your pipe a little and **use 45 degrees elbow to make it corresponding to the pavement.**
Once You make that connection short enough, the slope shouldn't be such a problem.
Another answer is to make some shape by yourself with concrete. You could make it form something like Craig posted above.
I'm afraid, however, that if someone start making a pavement, Your work may be spoiled by the need od changing level or something...